# How should I respond to the professor who told me he has only a MSc student opening when I asked about PhD openings?

Tags: phd, international-students

I have writen to a professor in Canada inquiring for a PhD position at his lab 6 months before in 2022. He requested
to write to him again in February and see.

I wrote to him today with resume, sop, and other documents. He replied to me by saying that, at this time, he only has funds for a MSc student and no funds for a PhD student. However, even though I already have a MSc in the same area from my home country, I am willing to take that MSc chance given the possibility of PhDs in my field in Canada in the future.

How to convince the professor and politely request to consider me for the MSc position?

Comment: A couple of questions: 1) are you trying to move to another country as part of your motivation, 2) was your MSc coursework based/thesis only/some hybrid. 3) Do you know what the project is, and is it something you really want to work on?

Also even assuming you were the best candidate for the job there may be some restrictions on who can be funded, perhaps the funding source may not allow for people with an equivalent level training to be funded. I've seen that for PhD funding (i.e. can only be given to people without a PhD). Though others might have a better grasp of this than I do.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest that you look elsewhere in Canada or beyond. If they say that they don't have funds then you are at risk of winding up with a delay and no real advancement. There is no guarantee that funds will become available in a time frame useful to you.

If you really think that you need another masters then just ask to be considered. You don't need any special wording, other than expressing interest in the opportunity which you would do in any case.

Note that getting a masters in a country doesn't give you much of an advantage for getting a doctorate there. You will normally be considered along with any other candidate on the usual terms.